# Study Guide/ Topics for Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer exam

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am planning to attempt Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer exam, But unable to fine any Study Guide or Study Material.

Please suggest if someone have any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

To Prepare use the links below to get a study guide:

Refer this thread for more details - https://community.magento.com/t5/Off-Topic/Magento-2-certification-exams/td-p/176

**Study Guide:**

Magento Free Study Guide: https://u.magento.com/free-study-guide

PDF Study guide by SwiftOtter:  https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-associate-study-guide

Comment: Can you please share the swiftotter guide with us?

Comment: @PushpendraSingh I would suggest you pay for them if you would like to read their content.

Comment: Sure, I will...

Answer (score 0):

You can consult with study guide made by Magento 2.
Reference website for certification are
https://belvg.com/tutorial/magento-2-certified-professional-developer-guide
Magento 2 Official Guide
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/